# Pandas - Induce an opening/closing bracket or induce a Negative sign before the number

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column which has data with circular braces missing at times: The output required is to either remove the braces and induce a negative sign before the number or add starting/ending braces if it's missing any. EX - "10,752)" to "-10,752" or "(10,752)"

input -

```
 0. 21,028 
 1. 11,689 
 2. 94 
 3. 10,572) 
 4. 2,261
```

Name: Sale , dtype: object

Output required

either -

```
 0. 21,028 
 1. 11,689 
 2. 94 
 3. (10,572) 
 4. 2,261
```

OR

```
 0. 21,028 
 1. 11,689 
 2. 94 
 3. -10,572 
 4. 2,261
```

Is it possible? Or, you can consider it as a String like this:

```
testz = '21,028 \n1    11,689 \n2        94 \n3    10,572) \n4     2,261 \n
```

Output Req'd:

```
21,028 \n1    11,689 \n2        94 \n3    (10,572) \n4     2,261 \n
```

OR

```
21,028 \n1    11,689 \n2        94 \n3    -10,572 \n4     2,261 \n
```

As you can see "10572)" is replaced with (10572) or -10572

Now I know how to remove the brackets all together  - `re.sub(r'[()]', r'', testz)`

but to induce one or replace the number with negative I'm not sure how.

if i add a new input:

```
0.        80,123 
1.         5,060 
2.      (4,756 ) 
3.     ( 16,572) 
4.    ( 14,673 )
Name: sale , dtype: object
```

or

```
testz = '80123 \n1    5,060 \n2        (4756) \n3    (16,572) \n4     (14,673) \n '
testz.replace(r'\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b(?!\))|\b(?<!\()(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)', r'-\1\2')
```

stops working. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Why do you try to remove the parentheses if you need them to identify the numbers? Also, if you write it using Pandas, keep to Pandas and show appropriate code. I think you need something like `df['col'].str.replace(r'\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b(?!\))|\b(?<!\()(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)', r'-\1\2')`

Comment: well, to distinguish them i either need to complete the parenthesis or add a '-' negative sign ahead of the numbers as they are negative numbers.. Thanks, I'll try what you have mentioned... :)

Comment: `str.replace(r'\((\d+(?:,\d+)?)\b(?!\)|,\d{3}\b)|\b(?<!\()(?<!\d,)(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\)', r'-\1\2')`? See https://regex101.com/r/jLFwek/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This code works for the given input but as soon as i change the input to:  

testz = '80123 \n1    5,060 \n2        (4756) \n3    (16,572) \n4     (14,673) \n 

it stops working.. do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: It [works](https://regex101.com/r/jLFwek/2) well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure if you are seeing the latest input Wiktor as when we have complete parenthesis, it stops working... Please can you check again or if you can open this question i may have more solutions from other people too that may work?..

Comment: Let's try to reopen the question, I will cast my vote. Can you please let know if you can use PyPi regex module, or are you for some reasons limited to `re`?

Comment: Is your data frame like `df = pd.DataFrame({'testz':[ '80,123', '5,060', '(4,756 )', '( 16,572)', '( 14,673 )', '10,572)', '(5,242']})`?

Comment: Check [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY@9CsIwFIX3PkW2JPVakrRJRZBugrgIrpnUoAXbhjRClb57TCuCTueHcz@49ulvXZuHUDe2cx45czVDknjT@xfaILxiwEUOSAJTDBApoJQK0egQVyBL8bEFqDKfas6@pQRRCJy4IWJmanbuGlvfDXFYE92n@rIg1Rqi0GqKlKTH/e4QZUvHeUF@J3T8j/MJpol1deuJG7L@cYropeZaYEDzB5SG8AY).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm seeing some anomaly in my data so had to get new data wouldn't look like this,thus i won't have to fix this issue now.. Thanks for your help though... I've saved the solution in case i come back to this!! :) thanks

Comment: Why "saved"? If it is fine and helpful, I can post as an answer. Is it helpful for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, my data is like the the dataframe you mentioned.. when I tried the query/script you provided, for some reason it wasn't working for all the circular parenthesis, was it working in your case?     

I'm not as such bounded to re, it's just that i have more familiarity of re then Pypi nothing else..

Comment: What do you mean by "cicular parentheses"? Please update the post if you need  a defintive answer. An answer can only be answered if you have a set of clear-cut expectations, requirements.

Comment: i meant the same input..that you've provided.. The query doesn't work for all the '()'  cases... Sorry i call '()' these as Circular braces...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew have you tried using the query for dataframe you've mentioned?coz i have the same dataframe :

pd.DataFrame({'testz':[ '102.3 %', '62.123 %', '(4,756 )', '( 0.1 %', '10,572)', '(5,242']})

and the query isn't working as expected: i.e to remove all the brackets and add a negative sign infront of the numbers where the parenthesis were..

Comment: This - https://pastebin.com/gwWn11Kb - works on my machine

Comment: If that works, I can even re-write it without using PyPi regex module

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it works perfect, Thanks:).. Just one last question is it possible to completely remove all the parenthesis even the complete one's'()' with the negative sign?..

if not, then this one would be enough for me too.. thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: So, `( 12334 )` must be replaced with `-12334`? Try `df['testz'].str.replace(r'\(?\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*\)|\(\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*\)?', r'-\1\2')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Man.. You are a Legend!! Yes it works Perfectly fine now!! You can close this ticket.. Have a good Day Sir!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a `-` before any number that is enclosed with at least one parenthesis on either left, or right, or on both sides.

Use an alternation-based regex:

```
df['testz'].str.replace(r'\(?\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*\)|\(\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*\)?', r'-\1\2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/888wrK/1)

**Details**

- `\(?\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*\)` - an optional `(`, 0+ whitespaces, Group 1: 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `,` and 1+ digits; then 0+ whitespaces and a `)` char
- `|` - or
- `\(\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*\)?` - a `(` char, 0+ whitespaces, Group 1: 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `,` and 1+ digits; then 0+ whitespaces and an optional `)` char

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the Details as well, i'm not really good at regex, i can understand it better now!! :)